# Run SQL Server Snapshot Agent automatically

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I am trying to setup automatic transactional replication. Basically I have some script files that are executed after each other. They set up a replication from one server to another and this works just fine. Only problem is, that it is never starts. If I look into the Snapshot-Agents status, I can see that it has never been run before. If I just click start in that dialogue, everything works as expected afterwards. But I don't want the user to have to Open the sql server studio and activate the snapshot agent manually.

What I already tried:

- running the snapshot.exe with all params set. It seems to work fine, but afterwards I get an error in my replicationmonitor that something from a path could not be read, but there arent any settings for a path, so I don't know how to fix this.
- exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job .. here I tried some params but I have no clue what to put here. My best guess was @job_name='myreplication' but I just get an error that it cant be found.

What is the easiest way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [sp_startpublication_snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176026.aspx).  You'll want to execute this at the Publisher on the publication database.

Regarding the error: *from a path could not be read*, you'll want to ensure the Snapshot Agent process account has sufficient permissions to generate the snapshot.  The process account needs the following permissions per BOL:

- At minimum, be a member of the db_owner fixed database role in the distribution database.
- Have write permissions on the snapshot share.
- The account that is used to connect to the Publisher must at minimum
  be a member of the db_owner fixed database role in the publication
  database.

This is covered in [Replication Agent Security Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx).

Comment: sounds like the command im looking for, gonna try it. @Error: The snapshot can be written, but the subscriber cant access it, which is wierd because as i read that the distributor should not be on the publisher, it instead is the same machine as the subscriber. The wierd thing is, that if i start the snapshot agent via gui, it works (but the files are written to the same dir ... it is just linked a little different, but i found no parameters for that)

Comment: Ok, forget about the error, the "sp_startpuublication_snapshot" works fine, thats exactly what i was hoping for :) Thx

Comment: @Flo Glad I could help.  I'd recommend posting on the [SQL Server Replication Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/threads) for any replication questions you have in the future.